# MATLAB: Subscript with a For Loop to Plot

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

In MATLAB, I am trying to build a for loop to plot the subscript pairs of `x,y` such as `x1,y1, x2,y2`, and `x3,y3`.  The goal is the for loop passes the subscript to the x and y and plots the 3 figures.
Here is the code:

```
x1 = rand(10,1);
y1 = rand(10,1);
x2 = rand(10,1);
y2 = rand(10,1);
x3 = rand(10,1);
y3 = rand(10,1);

for i = 1:3
plot(x(i),y(i))
end
```

However, I am getting an error.  So how do I use a for loop to subscript through the data for plotting?

Comment: That's the reason you should never create dynamic variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x(1)` cannot evaluate to `x1` and so on. Dynamic variables lead to problem like yours. Do not create them in the first place. Use an ND-matrix if your data has the same size or a cell-array/structure otherwise.

```
x = rand(10,1,3);
y = rand(10,1,3);

for k = 1:3
    figure;
    plot(x(:,:,k),y(:,:,k));
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I see. As pointed out in the comments, don't do that. A much better approach would be (assuming all you variables are the same size):

```
X = rand(10,3);
Y = rand(10,3);

for k=1:size(X,2)
    figure
    plot(X(:,k),Y(:,k)) % creates 3 different figures
end
```